# What do you call a topology where every open set is compact?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, compactness

The title basically says it all. I have a topological space $(X, \tau)$ where each $U \in \tau$ is (open cover-)compact (or quasi-compact, as they say in france). What do I call $\tau$?

Comment: Quasi-compact usually just means "open-cover-compact, but not necessarily Hausdorff". In some traditions, "compact" also implies Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. These are exactly the Noetherian spaces!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_topological_space

Comment: It's quite a trivial argument actually, once you know that Noetherian spaces are precisely the hereditary compact ones.